# Conditional flow within the different blocks in resource blocks of terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to create a terraform script which takes user input and executes accordingly. I basically want to ask if the user wants static IP in Google cloud platform, if yes, then stitch the resource "google_compute_instance" accordingly, otherwise, let it go.

Sharing the code I have written:

```
variable "create_eip" {
  description = "Enter 1 for true, 0 for false"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "external" {
  count = "${var.create_eip}"
  name = "external-ip",
  address_type = "EXTERNAL",
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "compute-engine" {
  name = "random",
  machine_type = "f1-micro",
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      size = "10",
      type = "pd-ssd",
      image = "${data.google_compute_image.image.self_link}"
    }
   }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = "default",
        access_config {
              nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.external.address}"
   }
 }
}
```

The error I'm getting here is when the user puts 0 as input the code control still goes to "nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.external.address}""

because of which I get this error:

> - google_compute_instance.compute-engine: Resource 'google_compute_address.external' not found for variable
>     'google_compute_address.external.address'.

I also tried it this way by replacing

```
nat_ip = "${var.create_eip == "1" ? "${google_compute_address.external.address}" : ""}"
```

(if create_ip = 1, execute "google_compute_address.external.address", else do nothing).

But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with terraform...

You can't really do an if for something other than the count.

You could try something like that as you can't put condition inside a resource for now:

```
variable "create_eip" {
  description = "Enter 1 for true, 0 for false"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "external" {
  count = "${var.create_eip}"
  name = "external-ip",
  address_type = "EXTERNAL",
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "compute-engine-ip" {
  count = "${var.create_eip == 1 ? 1 : 0}"
  name = "random",
  machine_type = "f1-micro",
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      size = "10",
      type = "pd-ssd",
      image = "${data.google_compute_image.image.self_link}"
    }
   }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = "default",
        access_config {
              nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.external.address}"
   }
 }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "compute-engine" {
  count = "${var.create_eip == 1 ? 0 : 1}"
  name = "random",
  machine_type = "f1-micro",
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      size = "10",
      type = "pd-ssd",
      image = "${data.google_compute_image.image.self_link}"
    }
   }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = "default",
        access_config {
   }
 }
}
```

This code will create a compute instance using the created ip if the variable value is at one, in the other case it will create an ip, you could also add a lifecycle if you want to keep the same ip on the compute_address resource:

```
lifecycle = {
  ignore_changes = ["node_pool"]
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but getting this error now. `Error: google_compute_instance.compute-engine: resource repeated multiple times` @night-gold

Comment: Yeah sorry... That's normal I forgot to rename the resources, I edited

Comment: Don't forget to close the question ;)